# JWPlayer embed not working

Tags: video, embed, jwplayer

the embed code given on the Lontailvideo website is not working. I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            file: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
            image: "ss.png"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

All that appears is the div tag which says "Loading the player...". I've added the relevant JS files it's asked for and specified the correct path, but to no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link we can take a look at?